# Empty caption of subfigure in memoir slightly misaligned

Tags: horizontal-alignment, memoir, subfloats, subcaption

Consider the following minimal example meant to illustrate a single figure with a subfigure using the `memoir` documentclass:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newsubfloat{figure}% Allow for subfloats (subfigures) within figure environment
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subbottom[]{\rule{2pt}{3em}\quad\rule{2pt}{3em}\quad\rule{2pt}{3em}}%
  \caption{This is a caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The caption of the subfigure is empty so that it only displays the subfigure counter - '(a)' in this case:

[image: Figure with subfigure in memoir class]

However, the subfigure label is not perfectly centered the way I had hoped with an empty caption. Changing the subfigure definition (using some negative spacing via `$\!\!$`) to

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newsubfloat{figure}% Allow for subfloats (subfigures) within figure environment
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subbottom[$\!\!$]{\rule{2pt}{3em}\quad\rule{2pt}{3em}\quad\rule{2pt}{3em}}%
  \caption{This is a caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

instead produces a more acceptable empty subfigure caption, however minuscule the difference:

[image: Figure with subfigure in memoir class]

Is this a known bug, or at least fixable?

Comment: that is the space between (a) and the caption. Seems like a bug because memoir already tests if the contents of [] is empty.

Comment: @Herbert Actually it doesn't test for emptyness, but it tests whether the contents is `\@empty`, which happens if there is no optional argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The label leaves a space before the subcaption; it's necessary to kill it if there's no subcaption.

```
\makeatletter
\def\@memsubfig[#1]{%
  \@ifnextchar [%
    {\@memsubfloat{sub\@captype}[#1]}%
    {\@memsubfloat{sub\@captype}[\@empty #1][#1\unskip]}}
\makeatother
```

### Some explanations

The complete syntax of \subbottom is

```
\subbottom[A][B]{<figure code>}
```

where A is the entry for the list of figures (tables) and B is the subcaption (they may be different just like captions for figures and tables). When B is not expressed, it's assumed to be the same as A. If also A is missing, no subcaption is set, not even the letter.

The control is actually passed to some other macros and eventually `\@memsubfig` is called when A is present (it will be substituted for `#1` in the code). This macro checks if there is another optional argument. If there is, then

```
\@memsubfloat{subfigure}[A][B]
```

will be evaluated, otherwise LaTeX will be confronted with

```
\@memsubfloat{subfigure}[\@empty A][A]
```

(Note: we assume to be dealing with a figure; for a table, `\@captype` would be `table`.) This in the original definition. With my definition we'll have

```
\@memsubfloat{subfigure}[\@empty A][A\unskip]
```

The `\@empty` is there for technical reasons, it's not important since that is what will be written in the auxiliary file. The task of `\@memsubfloat` is also to typeset the subcaption and it basically does

```
(a)\space A\unskip
```

where "a" is the "number" (the `\unskip` isn't there with **memoir**'s definition); if now A is empty, as in your case, the `\unskip` will kill the `\space`, otherwise it will do nothing. Bingo!

Of course, if you have captionless subfigures, you won't put subcaptions in the list of figures.

Comment: If and when you have the time and patience, could you annotate that? I appreciate among experts it's probably obvious, but for us noobs an annotation would be a useful learning resource. If you don't have the time, of course I understand.

Comment: suggested fix will be added in the next release